# Table border in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm Trying  to create a table with a rounded border, but only in the bottom. I'm using this CSS coder:

```
#table_rounded_white{
            border-style: solid; 
            /*border-top-style: none;*/
            border-width: 1px;
            border-color: #8E8C8C;
            border-radius: 15px;
            -moz-border-radius: 15px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            padding: 10px;
        }
```

What I need is to do the top borders without rounding them.

Someone have an idea about how to do this?

Thank You

Comment: It might be wiser to put the rounded border on a container div than the table itself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

rather than defining all radii for each corner:

```
border-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
```

only define the radii you need:

```
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 15px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 15px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
```

here's a handy-dandy tool to generate styles quickly: http://border-radius.com/